# Valums uploader plugins - Upload file on form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4, fine-uploader

I have used Valums uploader plugins for file uploads in asp.net mvc4. But I want to upload files on form submit. So I used following code and set "autoUpload" option to false. Here is my code :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          var manualuploader = $('#manual-file-uploader').fineUploader({
              request: {
                  endpoint: ''  
              },
              autoUpload: false,
              text: {
                  uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Files'
              },
              debug: true,
          });

   });
```

As you can see I didn't pass any url to endpoint because I need to save files and all model properties in database on form post.I tried to access "qqfile" attribute in my controller action But no luck.
Here is my controller action

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ViewModel model,string qqfile)
        {
        }
```

how would I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You MUST specify an endpoint.  If you want to defer uploading, simply set autoUpload to false, as you have already done, and then call the uploadStoredFiles() function when you want to start the upload.

Comment: But I need to upload files on form post. So I can't trigger uploadStoredFiles() function directly.also need to save all model properties. If I trigger uploadStoredFiles() then how would I get all model properties value on server side ?

Comment: Send the properties as parameters using setParams or the params option.  Trigger uploadStoredFiles whenever you want, via javascript.

Comment: Its pretty ridiculous that there is no way to make this component do nothing more than append input type=file elements to a container...

Comment: @Sam please try to speak civilly in these forums.  There is absolutely no reason to be rude.  You are the first to request such a feature, which is why it does not exist.  I assume you are the one who opened a feature request.  I'll comment on it today.

Comment: If anyone else is interested in following @Sam's feature request, please have a look [here](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/781).

Comment: Right, sorry. Misdirected frustration.